# Spring JPA with postgre Sequence Duplicate Value on Primary Key on multiple nodes of the application

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, sequence

i'm stuck on an issue and haven't been able to find a viable solution for that.

We have an application where two JPA entity are using the same sequence to generate ids (it's wanted)

```
-- Father class
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "gen1", sequenceName = "sx_seq", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "gen1")
@Column(name = "id", unique = true)
private Long id;
```

with two child (both of them extend the father with a couple differences).

From time to time the database it's throwing a duplicated primary key on one of them (not the other one), in an environment where we have three istances of this application.

We have another application that instead works (with also three nodes) but the difference it's that both entity a and entity b are not extending a father class, can be this the solution in this case?

I would also like to add the on the configuration of jpa we have:

```
spring.jpa.open-in-view = false
```

Comment: Sequencing is fetched by your JPA provider and then used for the insert, so to figure out what is going on, you'd have to debug what values it is getting from the sequence and clues on the inserts to see why it might be reusing a value (if the sequence isn't returning the same value twice, which should occur). Turn on as much logging as you can and see if you can set up a situation that reliably reproduces it.